# ios swift large tableview cell data update in every second

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

What if i create a tableview with large amount of data cells thats need to be update in every second depends on server data. How can we get the data and update it simultaneously in every second?

Comment: Add observer for updating tableview if data is updated from server. You need to call API for new data or there is socket like mechanism for updated data, So you can simply update your tableview after web call.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the use-case you are trying to implement.

While you can simply use a `Timer`, for achieving what you want to achieve i.e.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And your code for fetching server data:

```
@objc func update() {

}
```

After receiving the data from server, you can call the `reloadData` method for your tableView and it would refresh the your table data.

---

But this might not be a good approach as it can increase memory load on device and it is wasting the resource like battery, CPU and data.

You might want to rethink about your architecture. Possible suggestions are:

1. Reload table rows which are being shown on the UI only.
2. Using a delta variable to load only rows which have changed on the server.
3. Let the server decide which rows needs to be updated. Using tools like Pusher and Firebase realtime database to achieve the same.

Would be able to help only if I get more context about your requirement.